# enable JMX in embedded jetty

Tags: jetty, jmx, embedded-jetty, ganglia

I want to enable JMX in jetty 9 for collecting statistics.
According to the documentation I have to do this as follows

```
Server _server = new Server();
// Setup JMX 
MBeanContainer mbContainer=new MBeanContainer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
_server.getContainer().addEventListener(mbContainer);
_server.addBean(mbContainer);
```

But it seems that Server doesn't have a getContainer API. 
How can I enable JMX ?

Also I want to collect these counters into Ganglia? Can I do this from my application or to I need a plugin for retrieving this using JMX ?

Comment: I think I found it. Just remove the _server.getContainer line

Comment: Try [JMXTrans](http://code.google.com/p/jmxtrans/). it can collect metrics from a JVM over JMX and then push data into graphite.